# How to condense this jquery to allow an unlimited number of options

Tags: jquery

I have this following jquery which will set all the elements with a class (ex. equal1) to match the height of the tallest element with that class.

This code only allows 11 different heights to be set. Is there a way to write this code so that the class could be anything that starts with equal-[suffix], such as equal-blurbs.

This way there can be an unlimited number of different groups of equal height elements with classes like equal-blurbs, equal-price, equal-boxes, etc.

```js
(function($) {

  // Window Load
  $(window).load(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (viewport >= 960) {
      equal_height($('.equal1'));
      equal_height($('.equal2'));
      equal_height($('.equal3'));
      equal_height($('.equal4'));
      equal_height($('.equal5'));
      equal_height($('.equal6'));
      equal_height($('.equal7'));
      equal_height($('.equal8'));
      equal_height($('.equal9'));
      equal_height($('.equal10'));
      equal_height($('.equal11'));
    }
  });

  // Window Resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (viewport >= 960) {
      equal_height($('.equal1'));
      equal_height($('.equal2'));
      equal_height($('.equal3'));
      equal_height($('.equal4'));
      equal_height($('.equal5'));
      equal_height($('.equal6'));
      equal_height($('.equal7'));
      equal_height($('.equal8'));
      equal_height($('.equal9'));
      equal_height($('.equal10'));
      equal_height($('.equal11'));

    } else {
      $('.equal1').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal2').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal3').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal4').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal5').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal6').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal7').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal8').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal9').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal10').attr('style', '');
      $('.equal11').attr('style', '');
    }
  });

  function equal_height(group) {
    var tallest = 0;

    $(group).attr('style', '');

    group.each(function() {
      var this_height = $(this).height();

      if (this_height > tallest) {
        tallest = this_height;
      }
    });

    group.height(tallest);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div.equal1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

column {
  width: 24%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </column>
</body>
```

Comment: Why you are using `class` like if they were `ID`? You could have the class `equal` to set the styles that all of them share and add another `ID or Class` to separate the behaviors you want to implement "individually"

Comment: because IDs should be unique. if I have multiple elements that I want to be the same height regardless of how much content they have, I would need to set a class. right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) or in case there are multiple classes for the element then it won't work as you expected in that case, use [attribute contains with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-with-selector/).

Now for grouping based on the class you need to iterate over the collection and need to call function only for unique classes to avoid repetition use an additional object.

For example, you can do something like this(assuming there is only one class for elements)

```js
(function($) {

  // Window Load
  $(window).load(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (viewport >= 960) {
      get_unique_and_call_equal();
    }
  });

  // Window Resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();
    if (viewport >= 960) {
      get_unique_and_call_equal();
    } else {
      $('[class^="equal"]').attr('style', '');
    }
  });

  function equal_height(group) {
    var tallest = 0;

    $(group).attr('style', '');

    group.each(function() {
      var this_height = $(this).height();

      if (this_height > tallest) {
        tallest = this_height;
      }
    });

    group.height(tallest);
  }

  function get_unique_and_call_equal() {
    var ref = {};
    $('[class^="equal"]').each(function() {
      if (!(this.className in ref)) {
      // if there is chance for multiple class for elements
      // then you have to extract the class name using regex
      //or some other way
      // for eg: this.className.match(/\bequal[^ ]*/)[0]
        var className = this.className;
        equal_height($('.' +className ));
        ref[className] = true;
      }
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div.equal1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

column {
  width: 24%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </column>
</body>
```

---

**UPDATE :** To make work with elements which have multiple classes(including `equal*`) then you can do something like this with [attribute contains with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-with-selector/).

```js
(function($) {

  // Window Load
  $(window).load(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (viewport >= 960) {
      get_unique_and_call_equal();
    }
  });

  // Window Resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();
    if (viewport >= 960) {
      get_unique_and_call_equal();
    } else {
    // I'd added space since multiple classes are seperated by space
      $('[class^="equal"],[class*=" equal"]').attr('style', '');
    }
  });

  function equal_height(group) {
    var tallest = 0;

    $(group).attr('style', '');

    group.each(function() {
      var this_height = $(this).height();

      if (this_height > tallest) {
        tallest = this_height;
      }
    });

    group.height(tallest);
  }

  function get_unique_and_call_equal() {
    var ref = {};
    $('[class^="equal"],[class*=" equal"]').each(function() {
      if (!(this.className in ref)) {
        // extract equal prefixed class from class list
        var className = this.className.match(/\bequal[^ ]*/)[0];
        equal_height($('.' + className));
        ref[className] = true;
      }
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div.equal1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

column {
  width: 24%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </column>

  <column>
    <div class="equal1">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </column>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, but this wouldn't allow multiple different heights on the same page. For instance if i had equal-boxes, and equal-blurbs, wouldn't they all be equalized together?

Comment: thank you @pranav-c-balan I think this is closer to what i'm looking for. But its not working for me. The user will be choosing the suffix in the class.

I'm using this suffix method in a different snippet and I feel like it could be used similarly like this, but this is definitely not working...

`$[class*="equal-"]').each(function(){
     var equalClass = Array.prototype.find.call(this.classList, function(clazz){
 return clazz.indexOf('equal-') > -1;
     });
     var suffix = equalClass.split('equal-')[1];
     var content = '.equal-'+ suffix;
 $(content).attr('style', '');
});`

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
(function($) {

// Window Load
$(window).load(function() {
 var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

 if (viewport >= 960) {
  equal_height($('.equal'));
 }
});

 // Window Resize
 $(window).resize(function() {
 var viewport = $(window).innerWidth();

 if (viewport >= 960) {
  equal_height($('.equal'));
 } else {
  $('.equal').attr('style', '');
 }
});

function equal_height(group) {
 var tallest = 0;

 $(group).attr('style', '');

 group.each(function() {
  var this_height = $(this).height();

  if (this_height > tallest) {
    tallest = this_height;
  }
});

 group.height(tallest);
}

})(jQuery);
```

I believe this code can be optimized furthermore, but I'm not sure what the `group` variable contains and is not clear why you need different classes to style the same way, depending on your DOM structure you could have them contained in a different element and that way you could point to them...

Comment: my question must not be clear enough. I'm not trying to make just one class the same height. I want this jquery code to work for any class that the user decides that they want a certain number of elements to be the same height, but also allow another set of elements be a different height. This was the reason for the equal1, equal2, equal3 classes. But that will only limit the user to 11 different heights. I'd like for there to be unlimited number of equalX classes to be used.